# Auto-Upload Contents Of Jekyll '_site' folder to remote on build?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp, jekyll

I'm building my blog in Jekyll in VSCode. I'm trying to set up my workflow so that building the project automatically uploads the contents of the '_site' folder to a remote folder on my web server (let's call it http://example.com/blog). I'm running into a few issues connecting all this up.

The biggest issue is setting up a VSCode FTP extension to work with a Jekyll project. I had been using [ftp-kr](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ruakr.ftp-kr), which did work - however, it uploads the whole '_site' folder onto my web server, rather than just its contents. This means that my site is now at http://example.com/blog/_site.

I've tried initialising ftp-kr in the _site folder itself, but every time the project is built, Jekyll deletes the JSON that holds ftp-kr's settings.

So, to conclude: I want a way to *just* upload the contents of the '_site' folder via FTP to a remote folder on build... ideally using VSCode!

Any help is appreciated.